# Cannot load images to java swing application

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource

I was just wondering how to load images to my macOS application written in Java. I have made my application run, however, there were no images were displaying. Here is the stuff I have done to create the application:

NOTE: this program worked before it was turned into application

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    public class A extends JPanel{

         public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

              super.paintComponent();
              g.drawImage(new ImageIcon("image.png").getImage(), 100, 100, null);

         }
    }
    public class B{

         public static void main(String[]args) {

              JFrame frame = new JFrame();
              frame.setSize(500, 750);
              frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
              frame.add(new A());
              frame.setVisible(true);
              frame.setResizable(false);
         }
    }
```

here are the steps i have taken to create my application:

1. created runnable jar file by using eclipse
2. downloaded App Maker 2 from https://sourceforge.net/
3. chose the jar file after clicking the icon with a text saying "JAR"
4. chose my icon(with icns extension)
5. clicked start
6. chose the respiratory to save the application
7. entered the name and the minor java version required(+1.5)
8. opened terminal and accessed the respiratory MacOS in package contents of the application
9. entered `chmod +x launcher`

Comment: First, don't load resources in your paint methods. Second `ImageIcon(String)` expects that a file, named `image.png` in the working directory of the application.  A better solution is to embedded the resource in the Jar (by including it in the `src` directory of Eclipse) and using `Class#getResource` to obtain a reference to it.  Personal, I used `ImageIO.read` as it throws an `IOException` when things go wrong.  `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/image.png")` (*nb: I'm suggesting you use a directory named "resources", but that's up to you*)

Comment: thank you so much @MadProgrammer !!!